# Alternative type energy storage to batteries?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, design

When designing portable devices it is usually the battery that stores its energy, because it has a high energy density that allows even small batteries to run up to a year, given appropriate circuit design.

In mechanical engineering, I am now making a project that is somewhat like a portable mechanical FSM, and it requires a power source that can last for a reasonable amount of time. We are using mechanical mechanisms because it can survive many events such as heavy rain and underwater usage unlike electronics.

We considered using a conventional battery for this case, but it would defeat the purpose to this design, and it would be best not to have to build a waterproofing/somethingproofing shield. Is there an alternative type of energy storage, suitable for these cases, to batteries?

(e.g. Springs, but it may break way before getting to the one-year rating.)

Comment: What size, energy, and type of power as input and output ?

Comment: I assume your FSM is not the Flying Spaghetti Monster. So, what is it?

Comment: @hdhondt No, it is a Finite State Machine. But good idea! xD

Comment: I know you said you do not want to use batteries. However, Sanyo's Eneloop batteries will keep 70% of their charge for 5 years or more. I use them for all my A and AA battery requirements. See http://panasonic.net/energy/battery/eneloop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [flywheel](http://energystorage.org/energy-storage/technologies/flywheels).

When spinning in a vacuum, with magnetic bearings, flywheels lose very little energy over time. While they are probably best for large-scale applications, e.g. as backup for other power sources like solar energy, they have even been proposed as a power source for cars - although I assume there could be serious problems caused by the gyroscopic effect of the flywheel. There was a vehicle called the [Gyrobus](http://www.damninteresting.com/the-mechanical-battery/) that used a 3 ton flywheel for energy storage.

I do not know of any commercially available flywheel energy-storage systems, so you may have to build your own.

Comment: Fun fact: I *believe* that the tokamak reactor at General Atomics San Diego uses flywheel power storage (at an off-site facility), since it can't just draw the massive amounts of power it needs directly from the grid.

Comment: Yeah, the mechanical device is laptop-sized, so I'm not sure if that would work well. Thanks anyway. I'll keep the flywheel in mind.

Comment: I don't think a flywheel can store energy for a year (http://energystorage.org/energy-storage/technologies/flywheels ), the best I found was "months" (http://home.earthlink.net/~fradella/homepage.htm ) - the standby losses can be small, but are not negligible.

Comment: Large flywheels can store energy for very long periods. Smaller ones will run down proportionally faster, though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on size, you could have a suspended weight and pulley system connected to a small generator ie use gravitational potential energy.

Another would be an ultracapacitor topped up by a solar cell.

If it is a very small power device you could consider [energy harvesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting) technology - just about everything is listed in the wiki article

Comment: For the gravitational one, it is portable as in like laptop size, so it probably won't work. Thanks for the other suggestions! I'll go check out the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compressed air energy storage.

Comment: Good idea. But what I am worried is that it may break before getting enough pressure to support the system for about a year.

Comment: @Lim Ding Wen: Well, pneumatic actuators are used in safety-critical emergency shut-down valves, so...